# Haskell: Iterate over three fields of two lists simultaneously

Tags: list, loops, haskell

While doing some audio filtering in time domain, I came to a problem I would solve in iterative languages with an index. In Haskell it seems a bit harder to code the algorithm. Okay, so here ist the point:

```
[x1 x2 x3 | x4 x5 x6 | x7 x8 x9 x10 ...]
|y1 y2 y3 | y4 y5 y6 | ]
```

Imagine two lists, the upper one is the source, the lower one is the target. I'm moving a window of 2x3 fields in size from left to right over both arrays, here in this example it's x4-x6 and y4-y6. 
y6 is about to get the result of a function which gets x4, x5, x6, y4 and y5 to process. 
Normally I would do this in haskell with a recursive function, but the point is, that this function calculating y6 is a parameter. It's one of 10 different filter functions with individual algorithms.
At the very beginning I only have x1 to calculate y1. In the next step I have x1, y2 and y1 to process y2. Step three takes x1, x2, x3, y1 and y2 to produce y3. And so on until y_n.
Currently I'm stuck on how to do this.

**EDIT:** A little more in detail

Now, here is the function like it would read in plain old C:

```
void processArray(int[] in, int[] out, int count, int (*filterFunction)(int, int, int, int, int)) {
    int index;
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        out[index] = 
            filterFunction(
                index - 2 >= 0 ? in[index-2] : 0, 
                index - 1 >= 0 ? in[index-1] : 0, 
                in[index],
                index - 2 >= 0 ? out[index-2] : 0,
                index - 1 >= 0 ? out[index-1] : 0,
    }
}
```

Comment: The second list doesn't exist in the beginning, it's the result list.

Comment: Could you please format this quesion a bit more readable? Like, with actual Haskell syntax, and code-snippet markdown for `x1` etc.?

Comment: Also, an actual algorithm, even if it's an imperative one, would help to answer the question.

Comment: @Hennes It doesn't matter that the second list doesn't exist in the beginning.  Laziness and sharing will make sure it works out anyway. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use local recursion to build this list.  You want to map some function `f` across 5 input lists, so the tool of choice is `zipWith5`.  The first list is essentially `0 : 0 : input`, the second list is essentially `0 : input`, the third list is just `input`, the fourth list is just `0 : 0 : out`, and the fifth is `0 : out`.

```
processArray :: (Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
processArray f input =
    let out = zipWith5 f (0 : 0 : input)
                         (0 : input)
                         input
                         (0 : 0 : out)
                         (0 : out)
    in out
```

This is a very similar trick to the Fibonacci sequence

```
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (drop 1 fibs)
```

Which lazily produces a list of all Fibonacci values very efficiently in terms of CPU performance, but can eat up all your RAM depending on how you use it.

As far as difficulty goes, this is defined using nothing but recursion, list cons, and `zipWith5`.  It'll produce a list as long as `input` is, which means it can theoretically be infinite.  It doesn't need to know the length of the list, and it doesn't need to check the index at each stage.  It also will produce these values lazily.  Overall, I would consider this significantly simpler than the C version.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'm still knew to Haskell and still often it's very hard for me to get from the imperative sight of a problem to the functional solution. But thanks for this idea; now I know what this zip function is good for.

Comment: @Hennes It's good for a great many other things as well, but when you're mapping a function over multiple lists `zipWith` and co. are the way to go.  It'll take some time to adjust from the imperative way of thinking, it certainly took me a while, but once you start recognizing the patterns (a skill that only comes from practice) it seems obvious.  This is the same with imperative languages, you have to recognize the pattern first then you can solve the problem.

Comment: @Hennes Please consider accepting bheklilr's answer, if it solves your problem.